# z/os properties for the dataset using MQFTE

Tags: ant, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

i am working with WebSphere MQ FTE.... is it possible to give z/OS properties for the dataset? Consider the transfer is from UNIX to mainframe....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely!  Please see *[Transferring files and data sets between z/OS and distributed systems](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/zos_transfers.htm)* in the WMQ FTE Infocenter for details.

Comment: Alloc Type: 
Allocation directory:
Alloc Primary: 
Alloc Secondary: 
RECFM:
LRECL:
Block Size:
Unit: 
Volume: 
Storage Class:
Data Class:
Mgt Class: 

Can all these properties be defined using mqfte.